# App links with same host name on different android apps behaviour

Tags: android, mobile, deep-linking, intentfilter, android-app-links

I have two android apps A1, A2

for A1 manifest file

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
          android:pathPrefix="/gizmos" />
</intent-filter>
```

for A2 manifest file

```
<intent-filter android:label="@string/filter_view_http_gizmos">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="http"
          android:host="www.example.com"
</intent-filter>
```

I have configured [www.example.com/.well-known/assets.json](http://www.example.com/.well-known/assets.json) file for both apps with their respective finger prints and package names

I have installed both apps (A1 and A1) on my mobile.

my question which of the following app(A1 or A2) will open when i click on link `www.example.com/gizmos` and will there be any ambiguity between A1 and A2?

Answer (score 0):

system will ask user in which app he want to open clicked URL. there will be two options: "always" and "only once"